# Linking an ID from a Database to an Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, enums

I have a table in my Database that is seeded it has 2 columns an ID and a var char Role. I know that the id 99 will relate to the Admin status but I don' want to hard code this value. Someone suggested looking into Enums to do this so far all the examples I've seen havn't made sense to me and they don't seem much better than hard coded values.

```
enum Role
{
    Admin= 99,
    Commoner= 1,
    Pleb= 3,
    King= 5
}
```

is there a way to concrete this relationship so that for example if someone incorrectly seeded the Admin Id as 9999 that my application could handle this and work as intended.

I know I could try something like

```
Admin = dataContext.Set<Role>().First(x => x.Name == "Admin");
```

but I was wondering if there a correct way to do this? Or has anyone done this differently?

Comment: An enum is hard coded as well. But it doesn't make sense indeed. It even makes it worse, because with an enum _all_ roles are hard coded. But you're going to need a hard-coded value one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load these values when application starts and hold them in a dictionary

```
var roles = new Dictionary<int, Role>():
```

I guess that these IDs should not change while the application is running, so once you have it loaded, you can look it up in the dictionary like

```
var roleForId = roles[id];
var idForAdmin = roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Role.Admin).Key;
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: ye that was similar to what I was thinking, another option is to use the web.config and transform the value for each of my environments. This might be cleaner i think?

Comment: It can be. Depends on how you intend to extend your application in the future.

Comment: I was just talking about it there with my team and we think it might be better just to fix this properly on the database side. Everything else is just a workaround for an issue that was caused by human error